# Angular input radio not showing changes made in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On page load, I have an Angularjs controller.js that is setting the scope model from an ajax response:

```
services.InitializePage().then(function (response) {
            $scope.DataModel = response.data;
```

Then a few lines later the model is changed:

```
$scope.DataModel.SameAsShipToAddress = false;
```

However, the radio button on the view is not updated with the new value and remains unselected:

```
<input type="radio" name="SameAsShipToAddress" ng-model="DataModel.SameAsShipToAddress" ng-click="setSameAsShipAddress(true)" value="true" />
<input type="radio" name="SameAsShipToAddress" ng-model="DataModel.SameAsShipToAddress" ng-click="setSameAsShipAddress(false)" value="false" />
```

NOTE: If I set the model outside the InitializePage method, then the UI radio button is updated. (and I verified with a breakpoint that the services.InitializePage().then(function (response) block is getting hit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-value` instead of `value`, or the value `true` or `false` will be treated as strings.